# Reload parent after closing Iframe doesn't update dynamic content (PHP/Smarty)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fancybox, smarty

I'm using **Fancybox** to load and Iframe with a form. After I post it, onsubmit calls "return **onSubmitForm()**"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onSubmitForm() {
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); 
window.parent.location.reload(true);
}
</script>
```

So Php/Smarty is loading the dynamic content **OK** in my database. I can also close the Iframe. BUT, **after reloading the parent, it's dynamic content is not updated.**

I have doing several tests and it only works occasionally (**1 in 10**). **The previous content gets sticky**.

I also started using "**nocache**" or "**caching=0**" (for **PHP/Smarty** variables). So far it doesn't help.

**If I reload manually the browser, it works.**

Thanks!

Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the iframe (with the form) just try closing the box

```
function onSubmitForm() {
  parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); 
}
```

...then, in the parent page (from where you called fancybox) add this API option to your script... something like

```
jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type: "iframe",
    width: 640, // or whatever
    height: 320,
    afterClose : function() {
        location.reload();
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: JFK! thanks for answering. I'm testing your API, but is not completely clear for me where to add it. For example if I add after **jQuert('.fancybox').fancybox();** the fancybox effect doesn't work.

Comment: show me how you are firing fancybox (from the parent page) and I could tell you where to put the API, otherwise see my edited answer.